# JSONArray getting error

Tags: java, php, arrays, json

`org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":"98747406","name":"adam","surname":"hfdd","age":"2","latitude":"54.2118","longitude":"16.1876","origin":"koszalin","destination":"sian\u00f3w","ride_id":"262243421","date":"2017-05-25 18:13:00"}] at jaPassengers of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Have anyone idea what cause this error? It occur when I try getJSONArray from server output e.g.:

output:

> {"iActualJoinRequests":"4","jaPassengers":"[{\"id\":\"98747406\",\"name\":\"adam\",\"surname\":\"hfdd\",\"age\":\"2\",\"latitude\":\"54.2113448\",\"longitude\":\"16.1876282\",\"origin\":\"koszalin\",\"destination\":\"sian\u00f3w\",\"ride_id\":\"262243421\",\"date\":\"2017-05-25
>   18:13:00\"}]"}

```
JSONObject joOutput = new JSONObject(output);
JSONArray jaPassengers = joOutput.getJSONArray("jaPassengers");
```

EDIT: Problem solved, solution in comment.

Comment: can you show how you are converting it or the line(code) where you are getting error

Comment: Update the code,how you are trying to convert into JSON array?

Comment: The cause is that it can't be converted, as the exception states.  The JSON isn't properly formatted as an array and cannot be parsed. If you want to fix the problem instead of asking why it happens, please post the code

Comment: To get better help sooner post [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: I edited post and describe method how i want to get this array. It isn't copy and paste from application, I paste code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt Clark, like you advised I'm trying to fix problem on server side. Code:

```
$aOutput = array('iActualJoinRequests' => $iActualJoinRequests, 'jaPassengers' => $aPassengers);
$joOutput = json_encode($aOutput, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
echo $joOutput;
```

cause error in java when I try to get JSONArray jaPassengers, but:

```
    $aOutput = array('iActualJoinRequests' => $iActualJoinRequests, 'jaPassengers' => '');
    $joOutput = json_encode($aOutput, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    $joOutput = json_decode($joOutput);
    $joOutput -> jaPassengers = $aPassengers;
    $joOutput = json_encode($joOutput);
    echo $joOutput;
```

works :)

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a [json parser](http://jsonparseronline.com/), the error would become pretty clear:

```
"jaPassengers" : "[{\"id\":\"98747406\",\"name\":\"adam\",\"surname\":\"hfdd\",\"age\":\"2\",\"latitude\":\"54.2113448\",\"longitude\":\"16.1876282\",\"origin\":\"koszalin\",\"destination\":\"sian\u00f3w\",\"ride_id\":\"262243421\",\"date\":\"2017-05-25 18:13:00\"}]"
```

Your *array* is actually encoded as a string.

To parse this, first fetch it as a string, then parse the resulting string as a JSONArray:

```
JSONObject joOutput = new JSONObject(output);

String makeShiftArray = joOutput.getString("jaPassengers");

JSONArray jaPassengers = new JSONArray(makeShiftArray);
```

*It would be better to fix this on the server side if possible*